# Validating a date in a file on SunOS 5.10

Tags: bash, perl, shell, date, sunos

I have a file with a list of dates in the format below: `yyyymmddhhmmss`

```
20150608141617
20150608141345
20150608141649
20150608141506
20150608141618
20150608141545
```

Would like to validate the correctness of these dates in case there are errors during generation in a previous process.

Correctness means that there are no spaces,length is 14 characters and the date is valid i.e. no date like `20151508141545`.

Is this possible in perl or bash?

Comment: Yes, it's possible with perl and bash.

Comment: ... or Python, or Lua, or C, or C++, or Haskell, or ... Show us what you've tried and what's not working...

Answer (score 1):

The following will do what you need, using a quick check for length, then the built-in `Time::Piece` module to validate correctness.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;

use Time::Piece;

for my $entry (<DATA>){
    chomp $entry;

    next if length($entry) > 14;

    my $date;

    eval {
        $date = Time::Piece->strptime($entry, "%Y%m%d%H%M%S");
    };
    if ($@){
        next;
    }

    print "$date\n";
}

__DATA__
20150608141617
20152525252525
201506081413454
20150608141649
20150608141506
20150608141618
20150608141545
```

To change this code to read from a file, above the `for()` loop, write:

```
open my $fh, '<', 'filename.txt'
  or die "Can't open the file: $!";
```

Then in the `for()` loop, change `<DATA>` to `<$fh>` and delete `__DATA__` and everything below it.

Comment: You shouldn't use/recommend strptime() for validation, the implementation accepts values out of range `say Time::Piece->strptime("20150231", "%Y%m%d")->strftime("%Y%m%d");` result's in `20150303`.